# Jersey ChunkedOutput - how to detect client disconnections?

Tags: java, jersey, grizzly

Using curl as the client, jersey and grizzly on the server side, I can not get server to detect clients disconnections. 
Even in the case when the server write message to the client the ChunkedOutput.write succeeds.

Is there a configuration either in grizzly or in jersey that can make writes to the chunked output fail?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like when using Grizzly - Worker-thread IOStrategy the ChunkedOutput object (Jersey object) does not recognise clients disconnects immediately.

I ended up using Same-thread IOStrategy. This might not be the best solution for all apps, but for mine it is great.

```
NetworkListener listener = new NetworkListener("grizzly2", host, port);
listener.getTransport().setIOStrategy(SameThreadIOStrategy.getInstance());
```

I also tried using the Worker-thread IOStrategy and lowering the write buffer:

```
NetworkListener listener = new NetworkListener("grizzly2", host, port);
listener.getTransport().setWriteBufferSize(bufferSize);
```

This has also worked when the bufferSize was smaller then the actual messages sent.